# Uploading a Revit file to Autodesk Forge OSS by Multer on a Node JS server with C# .NET HTTPClient

Tags: c#, node.js, dotnet-httpclient, autodesk-forge, multer

I have a `node.js` server using **autodesk forge** by [Forge Node.js SDK](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-nodejs-client). For uploading an object I have used [uploadObject()](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/docs/ObjectsApi.md#uploadObject) method and **multer** middleware like what has been said [here](https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/datamanagement/oss/nodejs). The code is like this:

```
router.post(
    '/objects',
    multer({ dest: 'uploads/' }).single('fileToUpload'),
    XAuth,
    async (req, res, next) => {
        fs.readFile(req.file.path, async (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                next(err);
            }
            try {
                req.setTimeout(0);

                await new ObjectsApi().uploadObject(
                    req.body.bucketKey,
                    req.file.originalname,
                    data.length,
                    data,
                    {},
                    req.oauth_client,
                    req.oauth_token
                );
                res.status(200).end();
            } catch (err) {
                next(err);
            }
        });
    }
);
```

And like what it has been said in [here](https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/viewer/2legged/ui) I can call this api by **Ajax** like this (I have used an `input` html element to get the file):

```
var file = input.files[0];
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('fileToUpload', file);
formData.append('bucketKey', bucketKey.toLowerCase());

$.ajax({
    url: '/api/forge/oss/objects',
    headers: {
       'x-auth': token,
    },
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function (data) {
        console.log('success: Object has been uploaded');
    },
    error: function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    },
});
```

I what to do the same process by creating a C# Revit plugin for uploading a Revit model. I mean how I can have an object similar to `FormData()` in C#.
I have tried below code by `HttpClient` and `MultipartFormDataContent`:

```
using (MultipartFormDataContent httpContent = new MultipartFormDataContent())
{
    Stream file = new FileStream(App.Path, FileMode.Open);
    httpContent.Add(new StringContent(bucketKey.ToLower()), "bucketKey");
    httpContent.Add(new StreamContent(file), "fileToUpload");

    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = App.Uri })
    {
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-auth", App.Token);

        using (var httpResponse = await httpClient.PostAsync("/api/forge/oss/objects", httpContent))
        {
            if (httpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                TaskDialog.Show("Upload", "success: Object has been uploaded"); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I got a `MulterError: Field value too long` error in my server and a `500: 'Internal Server Error` response to my Revit plugin.

Comment: The endpoint of  PUT object to bucket does not accept multipart/form-data. The help tells: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-:bucketKey-objects-:objectName-PUT/  . The FormData workflow with the LearnForge sample is just for the sample itself. i..e. when the user uploads a file from client, it will post bucket name as well as file stream. While on server side, ObjectsApi().uploadObject is finally implemented by putting file stream: https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/src/api/ObjectsApi.js#L551-L595

Comment: in NET SDK of Forge, it shows the codes on uploading object . probably it could help . https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-dotnet-client/blob/24d9da4a1be19aef38c088a1a854de4e45c1efb5/src/Autodesk.Forge/Api/ObjectsApi.cs#L2819-L2909

Comment: @XiaodongLiang Thanks so much. Considering the links you sent, I think I should set `ContentType` to `"application/octet-stream"`.

Comment: great to know it helps :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Xiaodong Liang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6510144/xiaodong-liang), I edited my code like below and it worked for me.

```
using (MultipartFormDataContent httpContent = new MultipartFormDataContent())
{
    byte[] byteArray = File.ReadAllBytes(App.Path);
    Stream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);

    StreamContent streamContent = new StreamContent(stream);
    streamContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");

    httpContent.Add(streamContent, "fileToUpload");
    httpContent.Add(new StringContent(bucketKey.ToLower()), "bucketKey");

    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = App.Uri })
    {
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-auth", App.Token);

        using (var httpResponse = await httpClient.PostAsync("/api/forge/oss/objects", httpContent))
        {
            if (httpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                TaskDialog.Show("Upload", "success: Object has been uploaded"); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```